# HTML5 Checkboxes: Which element should have the 'aria-describedby'-attribute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, wai-aria

I currently write a user-interface for a search page on a local application. This search must have checkboxes to limit the scope of the search query. To make this functionality accesible I want to use "wai-aria"-Attributes.

So far my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-bd-1">
    <label for="check-bd-1">Band 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-bd-2"></input>
    <label for="check-bd-2">Band 2</label>
  </div>

  (... and so on...)

  <p id="help-check-band" class="form-control-static">Helptext...</p>
</div>
```

I want to use a "aria-describedby"-Attribute to reference the helptext, identified by "help-check-band". This text is appropriate for each input of this group.

My question is: Where should I put the "aria-describedby"-attribute? Is it neccesary to put it on each `<input>`-element, or does it suffice to put it in the topmost `div` (with class "input-group")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [The Mozilla Dev-Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute) both ways seem to be possible. "aria-describedby" can be utilized by the container and the input elements. Since the attributes on the `input`-Element correspond directly with the functionality, this way seems to fit this case.